# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to \pi/2} (\tan x)^{\tan2x}=1$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How do I prove that the limit of the following function is $1$?

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \pi/2} (\tan x)^{\tan2x}$

I shouldn't use l'Hôpital's rule.

I have proven  that limit is greater than $1$ but couldn't sandwich on the other side (I mean, the limit is less than $1$).

Comment: write $\tan x = y$, then the limit you are trying to find is $y^{\frac{2y}{1-y^2}} = y^{\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{1+y}}$ as $y \to \infty$ .. can you find another suitable change of variable from this point and evaluate the limit via a very well known standard limit form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=log(tan x)$
$\lim_{x\to{\pi/2}}$

Then  $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}log((tan (x))^{tan2x})=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}tan2x(\log {tan (x)})$

Using $tan2x=2 tan (x)/(1+tan^2x))$

$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}tan2x(\log {tan (x)})=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{2e^y}{1-e^{2y}}y$

$=\frac{2y}{e^{-y}-e^y}=\frac{2}{\frac{e^{-y}}{y}-\frac{e^y}{y}}$

But

$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{e^{-y}}{y}=0$

$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{e^{y}}{y}=\infty$ as $e^y/y=1/y+1+y/2!...$ by Taylor expansion

So

$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{2}{\frac{e^{-y}}{y}-\frac{e^y}{y}}=0$
$\implies \lim_{x\to\pi/2}log((tan (x))^{tan2x})=0$
$\implies \lim_{x \to \pi/2}tan(x)^{tan 2x}=1$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\tan x<0$ for $\pi/2<x<\pi$ we can assume the function is defined only for $0<x<\pi/2$ (a left neighborhood of $\pi/2$).

In all these case it's better to compute the limit of the logarithm:
$$
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan2x\log\tan x=
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}-\frac{\log\cot x}{\cot2x}=
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}-\frac{2\cot x\log\cot x}{\cot^2x-1}
$$
by applying $\tan x=\frac{1}{\cot x}$ and the duplication formula
$$
\cot2x=\frac{\cot^2x-1}{2\cot x}.
$$
Now you can substitute $t=\cot x$ and get
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{2t\log t}{1-t^2}
$$
and you should know how to manage this form. Hint: the limit is $0$.

Comment: And since the limit of the logarithm of the function is $0$, the limit of the function is $1$.